# Text config file encryption on Linux system for security

Tags: linux, encryption

I plan to use newsbeuter for console RSS reading.
This program has a config text file where I need to store my Google account password,
in order to access my Google reader.

I don't feel easy at making my password readable to everyone.

Is there anyway I can somehow encrypt this information ?

Comment: how can i move it there myself ?

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to automatically move it there yourself.  If the vote passes it will get moved "cleanly", i.e. linked from here, answers moved and no duplicates created.

Answer (score 3):

You could:

- [Encrypt your home directory](http://ecryptfs.sourceforge.net/ecryptfs-faq.html)
- [Use google per application passwords](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/advanced-sign-in-security-for-your.html), which are part of the two factor authentication system they added recently, in order to support "legacy" applications than don't understand two-factor auth.